# Advanece SQL Update query

Tags: sql-server

Question:

Want to update Inflow by checking the condition what is the value we have under inflow column in reporting table
e.g if we have a CASE WHEN FLAG = '1' THEN 'AS' ELSE 'LI' it should check the value for flag column if it is 1 then value should be 'AS' else 'L1'
Note: INFLOW column under reporting have different values.

Table Structure:

```
create table dummy ( ID VARCHAR(10), PRODUCT VARCHAR(10), INFLOW VARCHAR(10) ); 
INSERT INTO dummy(ID,PRODUCT) VALUES('10','999') 
INSERT INTO dummy(ID,PRODUCT) VALUES('11','888') 
INSERT INTO dummy(ID,PRODUCT) VALUES('12','111') 
INSERT INTO dummy(ID,PRODUCT) VALUES('13','222')

create table REPORTING_FLAG
(
ID VARCHAR(10),
PRODUCT VARCHAR(10),
INFLOW VARCHAR(2000),
FLAG VARCHAR(10),
L3 VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO REPORTING VALUES('10','999','CASE WHEN FLAG = ''1'' THEN ''AS'' ELSE ''LI''','1','SALR') 
INSERT INTO REPORTING VALUES('11','888','CASE WHEN L3 = ''SALR'' THEN ''SALR'' ELSE ''OTHR''','1','XYZ') 
INSERT INTO REPORTING VALUES('12','111','ABC','2','PQR') 
INSERT INTO REPORTING VALUES('13','222','SAP','3','QWE')
```

Comment: which is the flag column?

Comment: Your table does not reflect your question... Please provide more details

Comment: Thx for the edit, but still not clear... What data is in `REPORTING_FLAG`? Is there only one single row? is the `ID` column a key column? Please [try to follow this advise: MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you will have to create a parser for column "Inflow" and then perform an operation based upon what gets parsed within the INFLOW column. A single update query wont be possible here, instead, you will have to write TSQL blocks to achieve this.

Comment: Hello Shungo, table name is Reporting.

Comment: Ash can you please help me to create a parser for column.

Comment: Shungo. Id is the primary key

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data from "dummy" table into 
"Reporting_Flag" table?

Comment: dot netter I am trying to enter a data from reporting table into dummy by checking Inflow condition.

Comment: SQL cannot parse the text. You would need to use some sort of dynamic SQL to parse it but even then I cannot see any logic that would allow you to do this unless the other values being inserted are variables...

Answer (score 0):

When performing larger inserts, it is wise and correctly-applied logic to perform transformation on the sets of data, rather than each individual row.

Even if this is unavoidable, do not make the mistake of being comfortable with myriads of update/insert statements,which not only costs resources but trashes statistics, fragments your indexes and drives alike.

Run a SELECT statement that uses a CASE logic and verify the results. Once you can safely perform this on the select statement, convert it to an Update statement (note your update can use joins)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
declare dummyproducts cursor for select ID, Product, Inflow from reporting
declare @ID VARCHAR(10), @PRODUCT VARCHAR(10), @INFLOW VARCHAR(2000)
OPEN dummyproducts
Fetch next from dummyProducts into @ID, @PRODUCT, @INFLOW
while @@fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    if CHARINDEX('CASE', @INFLOW) > 0
        set @Inflow = @inflow + ' end'
    else
        set @inflow = 'r.inflow'
    set @sql = 'Update dummy set INFLOW = ' + 
                    @INFLOW  
                + ' from
                reporting r inner join dummy d on r.Product = d.Product and r.ID = d.ID where d.ID =  ' + @ID + ' and d.Product = ' + @Product
    print @sql
    exec (@sql)
    Fetch next from dummyProducts into @ID, @PRODUCT, @INFLOW
END
close dummyProducts
deallocate dummyProducts
GO
```

Comment: Thanks ash, got the output that i was looking for.

Comment: Good to know, but dont forget to update if this solved your problem statement

Comment: Hello Ash, can you please tell me what do you mean dont forget to update if this solved your problem statement. Because executing the cursor got the valuer in dummy table for inflow column.

Comment: glad to know, was referring to marking as solution if this solved.